# Informatica-MarkLogic Re-Try Mechanism

Tags: http, marklogic, informatica, marklogic-dhf

Is there a re-try mechanism for all the calls(Services) initiated through Informatica to MarkLogic?

If yes, please provide the documentation or link for it.

Answer (score 0):

By definition, retry of requests occurs on the client and not the server.

The MarkLogic Java API, for instance, supports retry of requests in cases where the payload is replayable.  (Streaming payloads can't be retried, at least not without reconstructing the input stream.)

In this situation, what is the client? If, for instance, Informatica is a client of the MarkLogic REST API, then retry of the request would have to be implemented by Informatica.